# ¿SQLite como ordenar de mayor a menor?

Tags: android, sqlite

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer un `ORDER BY` u ordenar la consulta de forma ascendente, este es el código que probé pero me manda error de que la aplicación se ha detenido.

```
public Cursor readData() {
    String[] allColumns = new String[] { DatabaseHelper.IDs,
            DatabaseHelper.MSG };
    Cursor c = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, null,
            null, null, null, null, DatabaseHelper.IDs+" ASC");
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes depurarlo e indicarnos el error exacto?

Comment: Veo que has puesto el tag andriod pero el codigo parece ser .net en c#, es correcto? Estas usando alguna libreria de acceso a sqlite, cual ? instancia de que clase es "database" ?

Comment: Gracias por responder, en el log cat encontre esto java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid LIMIT clauses:_id ASC     el lenguaje es android, libreria bueno nose creo las que importo son de cursor, y databasehelper

Comment: @JESUSESPINOSA pudiste resolver esto? suena como que tu tabla no tiene la columna default con el nombre _id , lo cual es muy comun.

Comment: @jirungary   asi cree la base de datos: db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + IDs + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + MSG + " STRING)");          la variable _id    public static final String IDs = "_id";

Comment: Si quito este fragmento, funciona pero, el orden es descendente, osea los registros nuevos los pone hasta abajo , DatabaseHelper.IDs+" ASC"

Comment: @JESUSESPINOSA que librerias estas utilizando para acceder a sqlite? porque analizando simplemente la documentacion el ORDER BY deberia aplicar http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_order_by.htm o se el problema no es de sqlite sino de la libreria

Comment: Creo que está pasando el String de ordenación en el parámetro `limit` en vez de usar el parámetro `orderBy`. El método que estás usando es  `query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)`

Comment: @gparis   gracias, inclusive el android studios me mostró una tablita con los parámetros XD

Comment: Como dice @gparis tenes el parametros de order en la posición de limit, es simplemente cuestión de ordenar los parametros con que llamas query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay un problema en el orden de los parámetros. La signatura del método es:

`query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)`

...pero se está pasando el `String` de ordenación en el parámetro `limit` en vez de usar el parámetro `orderBy`.

Comment: muchas gracias @gparis

Answer (score 2):

Según la [documentación oficial de Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) (en inglés), hay cuatro tipos diferentes de query:

- `query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)`
- `query(boolean distinct, String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal)`
- `query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)`
- `query(boolean distinct, String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)`

En tu caso particular, estás usando:

```
database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, null,
        null, null, null, null, DatabaseHelper.IDs+" ASC");
```

que se correspondería con el primer caso de arriba (con 8 parámetros). Entonces el problema es que estás pasando los el parámetro de ordenación en el lugar donde corresponde el del límite (debería ser el séptimo, pero aparece en octavo lugar).

La solución sería cambiar el orden de los dos últimos parámetros para que se ajuste al primer caso, o eliminar uno de los `null` (y se ajustaría al tercer caso):

```
Cursor c = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, null,
        null, null, null, DatabaseHelper.IDs+" ASC", null);
```

o

```
Cursor c = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, null,
        null, null, null, DatabaseHelper.IDs+" ASC");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Alvaro Montoro

Answer (score 0):

Ud. puede usar este código de Python:

```py
tables_connection_db.execute("SELECT colum_1_db FROM TABLE_DB ORDER BY  colum_1_db ASC ") # ORDENAR DE MENOR A MAYOR

tables_connection_db.execute("SELECT colum_1_db FROM TABLE_DB ORDER BY  colum_1_db DESC ") # ORDENAR DE MAYOR A MENOR
```

[También puede consultar este tutorial del Sitio SQLLite Tutorial (en inglés).](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-order-by/)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).